# Are dict() and add_csrf() the same?

Tags: python, django

I have two similar functions and I was wondering if `dict` and `add_csrf` are the same?

Do they both return a value that is related to variables in the template?

```
def main(request):
    """Main listing."""
    forums = Forum.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("forum/list.html", dict(forums=forums, user=request.user))

def forum(request, pk):
    """Listing of threads in a forum."""
    threads = Thread.objects.filter(forum=pk).order_by("-created")
    threads = mk_paginator(request, threads, 20)
    return render_to_response("forum/forum.html", add_csrf(request, threads=threads, pk=pk))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of.

`dict()` is a built-in Python function (or possibly a class - I'm not very up on my Python details) that accepts named arguments, and returns a Python dictionary.

As `render_to_response` expects a dictionary (or rather a Django context object, but a dictionary will do) as its second argument, you can use `dict()` there. You could equally use a dictionary literal:

```
render_to_response("forum/list.html", {"forums":forums, "user":request.user})
```

I [can't find any reference to `add_csrf` in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/search/?q=add_csrf&release=6), so I imagine it's a helper function someone's written to do CSRF-related stuff. ([@CrazyShezy notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14935714/20578) that it adds the CSRF token to the context passed to the template.)

As its result is being passed as the second argument to `render_to_response`, it must return a dictionary (or Django context object) too.

Answer (score 3):

`add_csrf()` is a function which returns a dict. It is used to add a csrf token along with the request arguments.

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def add_csrf(request, **kwargs):
    """
        Add CSRF to dictionary.
    """
    d = dict(user=request.user, **kwargs)
    d.update(csrf(request))
    return d
```

Where as `dict()` is a python built-in function used to create a dict